# Tools for monitoring wifi?

Tags: linux, wifi, monitoring

is there any tools in linux for :

- **monitoring** *upload* and *download* traffic
- host ip and mac using (that is live)
- device name

  of all users who use our wifi or local network?

Comment: [Wireshark](https://wireshark.org) would be a good place to start

Answer (score 1):

You are asking for **one** tool to explore a whole field of IT.
There are multiple tools for doing these kinds of things, but it all depends on what you want and how easily you want to process the information.

The mother of monitoring all networking traffic going through you card is [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/).
To get all the network traffic through your networking-card you should explore tools like [Bettercap](https://www.bettercap.org/).

If you only want to know the hostname, MAC and IP you should use [nmap](https://nmap.org/). This will scan your network and give you some results on the hosts and services available (live) on your system

A good tool which is very easy to use to just get IP an MAC adresses on your network is [arp-scan](https://linux.die.net/man/1/arp-scan)